# What is the origin of this photo of a young girl with the caption "The world you were raised to survive in no longer exists"?

Tags: photography, 9-11

[Link to the photo](https://64.media.tumblr.com/7e18ba53357bc6ee61b63db9d6d0faa4/c3aaedef9b658f73-2a/s1280x1920/6fee610a86927983a9ef8f4ebc36669b937cae67.png) (from an unrelated, random blog)

[image: Photo of young girl in a park, with WTC towers in background.]

This was obviously taken some time before 9/11 given the Twin Towers in the background. I have seen this picture many times over the last two decades with a variety of captions, but the one displayed here is the most common. However, I've been unable to pinpoint the origin of the picture itself. The most probable hypothesis is that it is a family picture that randomly made its way to the internet (assuming the image is not a montage to begin with), but I am curious to know if there is any context available.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any claim, just asking about the origin of something which is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That photo appears to be copied from the version here: https://starecat.com/the-world-you-were-raised-to-survive-in-no-longer-exists/ but with the bottom portion cropped off.  Bottom right attributes to "Damie Leigh".

(The main point being that the version in OP isn't the whole photo, but I can't verify what Damie Leigh's role was.)

Comment: See "In Loving Memory of Damie Leigh" on Facebook  https://www.facebook.com/groups/1527259247717070

Comment: @GEdgar I see, but I don't understand.  There is this too: https://www.facebook.com/damie.donkasaurus